# Generating divs in php?

Tags: php

Say I have the following div:

```
 <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Bodies</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Pickguards</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I would want this to be repeated a certain number of times so the resulting html would look like:

```
 <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Bodies</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Pickguards</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Bodies</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Pickguards</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Bodies</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Guitar 
          Pickguards</a></li>
      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

If the number was 3. What php command is used to do this sort of thing? (I know I use a for loop, but I mean the code in between)

Essentially what I will eventually have is something like this:

```
for each product
div product
text from product file
close div product
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a better example of what the result should look like? I presume you don't actually want 3 identical divs, but 3 divs with the same structure but different content? (Please explain why if you really do. There might be other ways to solve your problem. And you should be using a class instead of an id, at the least then.)

Comment: Yes, same structure different content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the foreach or while like this:

```
foreach($array as $value){
?>
<div>
whatever <?php  other php here ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='nav'>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<li class='navbutton'><?php echo $product->text; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

if you have multiple different divs, make a foreach loop for that too, if you want same div to repeat 3 times, wrap it around a for loop

Comment: you can use `<?=$product->text?>` instead of `<?php echo $product->text; ?>` but it will be deprecated in the next versions of php.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? 
for ($results as $value) {

echo '<div id="nav">';
echo '     <ul>';
echo '      <li class="navButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>';
echo '      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">'.$value['name1'].'</a></li>';
echo '      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">'.$value['name2'].'</a></li>';
echo '      <li class="navButton"><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">Contact Us</a></li>';
echo '    </ul>';
echo '  </div>';
}
?>
```